# Stopping miners in mix-ide

Tags: mix

Is it possible to stop miners in mix-ide and only run them when debugging or running contracts?

The default setting makes use of 4 addresses (accounts) out of which one is a miner. The issue is that the miner is multithreaded and takes up all available CPUs making the machine very slow.